# Elif statements in list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, syntax, list-comprehension

Why am i getting invalid syntax in this code:

```
def rgb(r, g, b):
    _list = []
    _list.append(r)
    _list.append(g)
    _list.append(b)
    _list = [hex(x).replace("x", "") if len(str(x)) == 1 and x >= 0 and x <= 255 else hex(x).replace("0", "").replace("x", "").upper() if len(str(x)) > 1 else hex(255) if x > 255 else hex(0) if x < 0  for x in _list]
    return ''.join(_list)
```

I edited my code as suggested by people can u explain me why my values aren't changing in the lists

```
def rgb(r, g, b):
    _list = []
    _list.append(r)
    _list.append(g)
    _list.append(b)
    for x in _list:
        if len(str(x)) == 1:
            x = hex(x).replace("x", "")
        elif len(str(x)) > 1 and x >= 0 and x <= 255:
            x = hex(x).replace("x", "").replace("0", "").upper()
        elif x <= 0 :
            x = hex(0)
        elif x >= 255:
            x = hex(255)
    return ''.join(_list)
```

rgb(-20, 275, 125) #Desired result = "00FF7D"

Comment: The code in your list comprehension doesn't make sense. It ends in `if x < 0 for x in _list` which is not any correct Python syntax. I suggest you break it up into smaller lines that make sense.

Comment: Your code does not have readability so prone to error

Comment: "Readability counts." > https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ 
Write a full suite of conditions and don't bother with complicated stuff.

Comment: @s.k can u help i edited

Comment: What values aren't changing? But in any case don't use a list comprehension like this

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one `else ""` in your final nested `if` statement. Like this, it works but not with the expected result.

```
_list = [
  (
    hex(x).replace("x", "")
    if len(str(x)) == 1 and x >= 0 and x <= 255
    else (
      hex(x).replace("0", "").replace("x", "").upper()
      if len(str(x)) > 1 
      else (
        hex(255)
        if x > 255
        else (
          hex(0) if x < 0 else ""  # <- here!
        )
      )
    )
  )
  for x in _list
]
```

Also, don't use a line like this in production code!

Comment: Ok i edited my stuff but why the values aren't changing here can u help